# What is the second life cycle once the component is rendered? - React Js

Tags: reactjs

What is the second life cycle once the component is rendered inside a react component?
I would say is componentDidMount(), do you guys have any other answer??

Answer (score 0):

These methods are called in the following order when an instance of a component is being created and inserted into the DOM:

1. constructor()
2. static getDerivedStateFromProps()
3. render()
4. componentDidMount()